# make carousel centered in page?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

```
<div id="imageCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="3000" data-ride="carousel">

                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                  <li data-target="#imageCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                  <li data-target="#imageCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                  <li data-target="#imageCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ol>

                <div class="carousel-inner">

                  <div class="item active">
                    <img src="pics/space_1.jpg" alt="Space 1">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                      <h3>Space 1</h3>
                      <p>Infinite Boredom</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="item">
                    <img src="pics/space_2.jpg" alt="Space 2">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                      <h3>Space 2</h3>
                      <p>Infinite Boredom</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="item">
                    <img src="pics/space_3.jpg" alt="Space 3">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                      <h3>Space 3</h3>
                      <p>Infinite Boredom</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                </div>

                <a href="#imageCarousel" class="carousel-control left" data-slide="prev">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                </a>

                <a href="#imageCarousel" class="carousel-control right" data-slide="next">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                </a>

              </div>


            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

I have a bootstrap carousel that is working fine. However, when I make my window fullscreen, it does not span the entire width of the page. What styling would I use in order to do this?

Comment: Need more code than that sir. What does your container look like?

Comment: At work rn, i will update later today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are following the correct nesting conventions. There may be an issue with your ".container" or ".container-fluid".

For more, reference: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: I have a container, yet lack the fluid portion. I see that now - thanks

Comment: Happy to help!!